# Pushing new branch GitLab

Tags: git, triggers, gitlab, continuous-integration, devops

I have GitlabCI like this.

```
STAGE:
  stage: deploy
  image:
    name: bitnami/kubectl:1.26
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
     ...
  rules:
    - changes:
      - .gitlab-ci.yml
    when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^release\/\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/
```

This job is for branches like release/x.y.z
The thing is that the CI is not triggered when I push the branch for the first time. As I saw from the GitLab logs it compares the last commit of the branch with the null commit (0000000000000000000000000000000000000000) and therefore it is not triggered. But it would be nice if it was triggered for first time the branch is pushed. What is the best practice in this situation?

I expect the CI to be triggered when I push the branch for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `when: always` to your rule:

```yaml
STAGE:
  stage: deploy
  image:
    name: bitnami/kubectl:1.26
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    ...
  rules:
    - changes:
      - .gitlab-ci.yml
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^release\/\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/'
      when: always
```

---

> Actually, when it compares the last commit with the null one, the CI file is new, and the "changes" condition takes place, it will *not* look for the second condition.

The `changes` clause in the first rule might be causing the issue indeed. When you push a new branch, the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file is considered new in the context of that branch, and the first rule with `when: never` is taking precedence.

So:

- We will explicitly include the check for the null commit SHA to make sure this rule does not block the CI when it is the first push.
- We will use a single rule for the branch pattern without involving the `changes` clause.

```yaml
STAGE:
  stage: deploy
  image:
    name: bitnami/kubectl:1.26
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    ...
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^release\/\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/ || ($CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^release\/\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/)'
      when: always
```

This configuration uses a single rule to ensure that the pipeline is triggered for branches that match the `release/x.y.z` pattern.
It also includes an explicit check for the null commit SHA, combined with the branch pattern check.
This should cater to both scenarios: the first push of a new branch and subsequent pushes.

Comment: result is the same(

Comment: @HenrikAmirbekyan For testing, can you keep the `when: always` and replace the if with: `if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^release\/\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/ || $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"'`

Comment: the same, actually when it compares the last commit with null one the ci file is new and the "changes" condition take place, it will not look for the second condition.